# Golang panic error while reading mssql query result

Tags: sql-server, go

I have a program that fetches users from mssql db and while reading them with Rows.Next() function, program gives panic error and I can't handle the error and make the program continue.
How can I achieve that functionality? I don't want my program to stop on error.

That's the function that executes the query and reads.

```
func connectServer(serverObj ServerObj) {
var (
    server   string = serverObj.server_ip // for example
    user     string = serverObj.username  // Database user
    password string = serverObj.password  // User Password
    port     string = serverObj.port      // Database port
)

connString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;port=%s", server, user, password, port)
conn, err := sql.Open("mssql", connString)

// Test if the connection is OK or not
if err != nil {
    recover()
    fmt.Println(err.Error())

} else {
    fmt.Println("Connected!")
    userSelectQuery := "SELECT name FROM sys.sql_logins"
    rows, _ := conn.Query(userSelectQuery)
    if err != nil {
        recover()
        fmt.Println("could not execute query")
    }
    usernames := []ServerUsername{}

    for rows.Next() {
        username := ServerUsername{}
        err := rows.Scan(&username.username)
        if err != nil {
            recover()
            fmt.Println("error")
            continue
        }
        usernames = append(usernames, username)
    }
    fmt.Printf("found %d users: %+v \n", len(usernames), usernames)
    defer rows.Close()
}
defer conn.Close()
```

}

Comment: The way you're using `recover` is just wrong. And you are deliberately discarding errors. Do not do that. Ever. You should handle errors, explicitly. Your functions should exit if they encounter errors and not continue. I'd recommend you take the [Go Tour](https://go.dev/tour/welcome/1) to familiarise yourself with the language because that snippet above has too many issues.

Comment: I wanted to achieve a logic like try catch, I know this is not error handling and question is about that exactly

Comment: Go does not support exceptions by design ([link](https://go.dev/doc/faq#exceptions)) and you should not try to emulate it. If you are asking what the appropriate way for handling errors is then you can read [Error handling and Go](https://go.dev/blog/error-handling-and-go) on the official blog. Or you can search StackOverflow. Or try googling. Error handling in Go has been addressed many times already. Examples are everywhere you look.